# Insert characters on start and end of regex result on javascript

Tags: javascript

i have problems inserting character in result of regex. I need do some like this:

```
var str = "Hello world, hello";
var regX = /he/ig;
```

The result have to be a string like this:

```
console.log(result); 
<mark>He</mark>llo world, <mark>he</mark>llo"
```

I tried using this code:

```
r = /he/ig;
str = "Hello world Hello";
var match, indexes = [];
while (match= r.exec(str)){
  indexes.push([match.index, match.index+match[0].length]);
}

indexes.forEach( (element) => {
   var strStart = str.substring(0,element[0]);
   var strBetween = "<mark>"+str.substring(element[0],element[1])+"</mark>";
   var strEnd = str.substring(element[1],str.length);
   str = strStart.concat(strBetween,strEnd);
 });

 console.log(str); //<mark>He</mark>llo worl<mark>d </mark>Hello
```

I understand where is the error, but i don't kwon how solve that.

Comment: why `d` character is wrapped with `<mark>` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `.replace()` method:

```
var str = "Hello world hello";
var result = str.replace(/he/ig, "<mark>$&</mark>");
```

The `$&` in the replacement string means that the matched text should be substituted.